# PHP Continue Statement Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: php, continue

I have a continue statement in my code. I thought the continue statement ended the current loop(inside) and started it over. It appears that the continue statement is escaping and starting from the very top (outside)loop. My question is if you have multiple loops with some if's thrown in, where does the continue go? To the very top loop or the most recent loop? It is also skipping the current record and gets the next record. The continue in question is in the while loop after the SELECT * FROM producers. I need the continue to loop back to the SELECT * FROM producers and get the next producer for assignment to the current ticket (loop at top).

```php
$x=0;
// Select Ticket ID  - Step 1 - Outer Loop

        // Get the selected ticket for display--------------------
            $tickets = @mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE statusid=4 AND flag='false'");

            if (!$tickets)
            {
                throw new Db_Query_Exception("DB Error: " . mysqli_error());
                exit();
            }

            // Assign variables to field names for display
    while ($ticket = mysqli_fetch_array($tickets))
    {
            $id = $ticket['id'];
            $ticketsub = $ticket['ticketsubject'];
            $sid = $ticket['statusid'];
            $emailid = $ticket['emailid'];
            $ticketdate = $ticket['ticketdate'];
            $authorid = $ticket['authorid'];
            $songid = $ticket['songid'];
            $tflag = $ticket['flag'];
            //Increment record counter
            $x=$x+1;
            echo "<p>Ticket Record Chosen-Count# .$x.</p>";

            //Check for suspensions and signed
            $sqlf = @mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id, suspended FROM user WHERE id=$authorid");
            if (!$sqlf)
            {
                throw new Db_Query_Exception("DB Error: " . mysqli_error());
            }
                while ($row8 = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlf))
                {
                    $uid = $row8['id'];
                    $suspend = intval($row8['suspended']);

                    if($suspend == 1)           //Songwriter Account is Suspended
                    {
                        echo "<p>This Songwriter is Suspended.</p>";
                        echo "<p>Continuing to next Songwriter.</p>";
                        continue 2;
                    }
                    elseif ($suspend == 0)
                    {
                        //Check if song has been signed
                        $sqlg = @mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id, signed FROM tickets WHERE id='$id'");
                        if (!$sqlg)
                        {
                            throw new Db_Query_Exception("DB Error: " . mysqli_error());
                        }
                        while ($row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlg))
                        {
                            $uid = $row9['id'];
                            $signed = $row9['signed'];

                            if($signed == 'true')
                            {
                                echo "<p>Song has been Signed. Looping Back...</p>";
                                echo "<p>Continuing to next song record.</p>";
                                continue 3;
                            }
                            elseif ($signed == 'false')
                            {
                                echo "<p>This Song has not been Signed.</p>";
                                echo "<p>Continuing...</p>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }



                //Get the producer record - Step 2 - Inner Loop
                $rstx = @mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM producers ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
                if (!$rstx)
                {
                    throw new Db_Query_Exception("DB Error: " . mysqli_error());
                }

                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rstx))
                {
                    $pid = $row2['pid'];
                    $email = $row2['email'];
                    $alias = $row2['alias'];
                    $pflag = $row2['pflag'];
                    echo "<p>Producer Record Chosen.</p>";

                    //Check the Association Table to see if there is already a Author ID / Producer ID Association
                    $astx = @mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM ProdTickAssn WHERE PID=$pid AND AUID=$authorid");
                    if (!$astx)
                    {
                        throw new Db_Query_Exception("DB Error: " . mysqli_error());
                    }

                    //Check if record is found
                    $rowCheck = mysqli_num_rows($astx);
                    if($rowCheck > 0)
                    {
                        //Matching Record Found. Go and get another Producer Record. Try again.
                        echo "<p>Matching Record Found in ProdTickAssn Table. Looping back.</p>";
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Write the Association Record to the ProdTickAssn Table
                        $sqlp = "INSERT INTO ProdTickAssn (PID, TID, AUID, Flag, DateStamp) VALUES ('$pid', '$id', '$authorid', 'True', CURDATE())";

                        if (@mysqli_query($db,$sqlp))
                        {
                            echo "<p>Associative record created successfully.</p>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Db_Query_Exception("DB Error: " . mysqli_error());
                        }


                        //Build the Pointer Record and write to Pointers table
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO pointers (tid, aid, prid, sid, pitchdate) VALUES ('$id', '$authorid', '$pid', '$songid', CURDATE())";

                        if (@mysqli_query($db,$sql))
                        {
                            echo "<p>New pointer record created successfully.</p>";
                            echo "<p>Pitch Sent to Email.</p>";
                            buildTemplate($db, $id, $pid, $alias);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Db_Query_Exception("DB Error: " . mysqli_error());
                        }


                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how your code is structured to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Re-posted with code.

Answer (score 1):

`continue` will ignore every thing that comes after it in the LAST `for` or `while` loop that it is in.

```
while () {

    for (condition){
        code1;

        continue;

        code2;
    }

}
```

`code2` will be ignored, so it is like there is no `code2` => it will reach the end of the `for` loop, check the `condition` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `continue` will affect the most inner loop it is placed in. Unless you use an integer argument like `continue 3;`, then it will go (in this case) three loops "up" and continue from there. See the [documentation of `continue`](https://www.php.net/continue):

> `continue` accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many levels of enclosing loops it should skip to the end of. The default value is `1`, thus skipping to the end of the current loop.